# Google Apps Script <= operator issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

We're writing a function to parse week number designations from a Google Spreadsheet column in the format of W#-W# (e.g. W1-10, W3-13, etc.) For some reason apps script is treating the <= operator *almost* as if it was an = operator.

The function:

```
for (var row = 0; row < qBow.length; row++) {
  var wRange = qBow[row][6];
  var wRsplit = wRange.split('W').join('');
  var wNums = wRsplit.split('-');
  var currentWnum = activeSheet.getName().substring(1);

  Logger.log('row: ' + row + ' currentWnum: ' + currentWnum + ' wNums[0]: ' + wNums[0] + ' wNums[1]: ' + wNums[1]);

  if (currentWnum >= wNums[0] && currentWnum <= wNums[1]) {
    Logger.log('row: ' + row + ' currentWnum: ' + currentWnum + ' wNums[0]: ' + wNums[0] + ' wNums[1]: ' + wNums[1]);
  }
}
```

Sample output from first Logger.log() :

```
row: 8 currentWnum: 4 wNums[0]: 3 wNums[1]: 13
...
row: 12 currentWnum: 4 wNums[0]: 4 wNums[1]: 13
...
row: 18 currentWnum: 4 wNums[0]: 3 wNums[1]: 13
...
row: 20 currentWnum: 4 wNums[0]: 3 wNums[1]: 13
```

*Full* output from second Logger.log() :

```
row: 106 currentWnum: 4 wNums[0]: 4 wNums[1]: 5
row: 138 currentWnum: 4 wNums[0]: 2 wNums[1]: 4
row: 139 currentWnum: 4 wNums[0]: 2 wNums[1]: 4
row: 151 currentWnum: 4 wNums[0]: 3 wNums[1]: 4
```

As you can see, it skipped all of the rows except for the ones where currentWnum is equal to wNum[1], and one row where wNum[1] is equal to 5. We tested it replacing wNums[1] in the conditional statement with a static number, and it behaves correctly. Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using `<=` on *strings*. I'd expect those to be compared lexicographically - so "13" is less than "4" for example.

I suggest you convert all the values to numbers (e.g. with `parseInt`) before performing any comparisons. That will go for every element in `wNums` and also `currentWnum`.

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem, thank you. We'd suspected it might be a string vs. number issue, but didn't pursue that route as we had checked already if the values were numbers with the isNaN() function. Does parseInt() do something to the values that isNaN() doesn't check for?

Comment: @BTEVC: `isNaN` just checks whether it's the numeric "not a number" value (used for things like imaginary numbers etc). Despite the name, that's not really checking whether it's a value of a numeric type. A string isn't a "not a number" value, despite the fact that it's not a number. I realize that's confusing :)

Comment: Got it, we just discovered that on our own also, by reading in just a little more detail about the two functions. Thank you for your help! :)